# How to show a string in every item in a foreach?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have a simple foreach in JSP but I want to add a simple string after showing each item?, can we do this?

This is my code:

```
<c:forEach var="res"  items="${listofitems}" />
<div id="items-0${status.count}" class="Someclass"><ul>
<c:set var="listofsomeitems" value="${items}" />
```

Comment: What to you mean by *"add a simple string"*? You can write any text you want at any time you want, e.g. `<div><c:out value="${res}"/>I'm write text I want right here after the value</div>`

Comment: Thanks Andreas, but this will be showed for all the items on the foreach?

Comment: It will be showed wherever you write the text.